# How do I access the "transform pattern" function in Illustrator on a French keyboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, hotkeys, keyboard

In Illustrator, "Tilde" key <kbd>~</kbd> seems to have some magical power:
According to Adobe's site, it can "*transform pattern (independent of object) when using Selection tool, Scale tool, Reflect tool, or Shear tool*".

Sounds great! I wish I could play around with it, but... I use a French keyboard. No such key on my keyboard.

[image]

<kbd>²</kbd> key is not working. And to access the tilde character, I must combine <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>é/2</kbd> keys, which obviously results to a duplication of the selected object.

I know I could change my keyboard through the Windows regional settings, but maybe there's another way. Maybe this key is hidden somewhere, or maybe I could change it through the keyboard shortcuts menu.

Any help appreciated.

Specs: CS6 - Windows 7

Edit : I do NOT want to type a Tilde. I want to find the key on my French keyboard that allows to transform an Illustrator pattern independantly of its container object. This has nothing to see with the thread "[How do I press the 'tilde' key on a French keybaord to access the "transform pattern" function in Illustrator?](https://superuser.com/questions/1291401/how-do-i-press-the-tilde-key-on-a-french-keybaord-to-access-the-transform-pat?noredirect=1#comment1912389_1291401)". This is not a duplicate... cheers

Comment: @Vincent feel free to move it you think it's irrelevant here

Comment: Vinny, perhaps you can change the topic to "How do I access this *function*". That way it is about Illustrator, and not about any keybaord layouts.

Comment: Ok done... maybe I shouldn't have edited my title then ^^

Comment: I can't test, but generally for language-specific issues like this, for some it's the key next to 1, but for others it's the key next to Z [or W for azerty]. UK/US keyboards have their tilde in opposite locations, Swiss/German tend to use the <> which is in the same positions as the UK tilde, even though it's a different character. & btw, tilde is always a shifted character.

Comment: @Tetsujin have tried the key next to w (which is <> all right). No luck.

Comment: Actually thsi si very adobe specific there is no alternative unless you bought a french version of illustrator

Comment: @joojaa Well, I do have the French version obviously. I also have the feeling it is Adobe specific, but I followed Vincent's advice to move the question to SU. Don't know really...

Comment: Doesn't it show in the key commands list in Illustrator? Can't check, I don't have CS6, Windows or an AZERTY keyboard :/

Comment: @Tetsujin no it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to do that without using the tilde by doing
`Object > Transform > [the transformation you want]`
and *uncheck* `Transform Object`.

[image]

---

The problem with the tilde is that Illustrator may on international keyboards
use a different key for it. You might try to experiment with some keys
until you find it, if it does really exist on the French keyboard.

Otherwise, you may use
[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap it to a different key.

Tracing, I found that the tilde key on the US and UK keyboards sends
the scan-code of `2B` and virtual key of `DE`.

This Autohotkey script replaces F12 by the tilde
(assuming that the French keyboard uses the same keys):

```
F12:: Send +{VKDESC02B}
```

To test it, install Autohotkey, create a file with the `.ahk` extension
and the above content,
then double-click it to launch.
If it works, you may add it as a startup file.

To replace F12 above by another key, see
[Autohotkey List of Keys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, as I said, I could easily overpass the problem just virtually changing my keyboard. Remapping the keyboard would definitely be an option if I need to use this feature a lot, but I don't really. I was trying to figure out if some of the Adobe feature were just not accessible to people using a non-US or GB keyboard. Apparently, this is the case. As a Adobe user, it stuns me...

Comment: As in my first option, it can also be done without the tilde.

Comment: Oh right, didn't answer to that... Well, it sounded very promising, but nope... that won't work. See Adobe's online help: Again, back to the "Tilde" feature https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transforming-objects.html#transform_an_object_s_patterns

Comment: The help seems to [indicate here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/transforming-objects.html#transform_an_object_s_patterns) that it will work. I added an image of a tool's options (if it applies here).

Comment: All right! My (stupid) mistake. Forgot to select the patterned fill in the appearance panel. https://i.imgur.com/eGZgPVG.gif That would probably be the best possible answer, Bounty is yours! Cheers ^^

Answer (score -1):

On my UK keyboard, pressing the <kbd>@</kbd> key rather than the tilde key (<kbd>~</kbd>) works!